# Customize json validation errors in play 2.1

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

I would like to provide a custom error message directly in the `Read` definition :

```
implicit val ar = (
 (__ \ "firstName").read[String].customError(ValidationError("bad format", "firstName")) and
 (__ \ "lastName").read[String] and
 (__ \ "address").read[Address]
)(Employee)
```

is this possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't have a `mapError` facility yet in `Reads[T]` or `JsResult`.
The best way to do that is just to redefine your own Reads[String]

```
implicit val StringReads = Reads{ json => json match {
  case JsString(s) => JsSuccess(s)
  case _ => JsError(Seq(JsPath() -> Seq(ValidationError("custom.error"))))
} }
```